# How in the universe does the crew know what's going on?

Tags: star-trek

In Star Trek, there's always bound to be a surprise. Whether it's an enemy attack or an undetected spacial anomaly, crews are bound to be caught on surprise. In these cases, it's hard to warn or inform the crew of the situation.

That was the case quite often in *Star Trek: Enterprise,* (which I just started watching recently,) when Trip repeatedly had to go to a communications terminal in Engineering and ask the bridge what was happening.

However, when ships are going on predetermined missions, the captain should be able to report the situation. We saw this once in the opening scenes of *Star Trek: Beyond*, when Captain Kirk gave a legendary speech about exploration, as well as the mission. We saw that his speech was visible and audible through terminals spread around the ship and data padds carried by the crew, and broadcast on the intercom.

That's probably just one example, and that might be more, but there are so few of those examples. So how does the crew know what's going on?

Comment: Submarine crews do the job that's in front of them. 98% of them have no idea where the sub is, what their mission is and when they're going back into port. They just maintain the torpedo rail, keep the engines running, perform firewatch, etc, etc.

Comment: Communication and information flow in *Star Trek* is designed to serve us, the viewers, first and foremost by presenting us with a dramatic production, rather than to tell the characters what they need to know. So sometimes people are stumbling around without knowing what's going on until it's expedient to tell us, other times we (and everyone else) have to listen to the captain droning on because it'll be important later.

Comment: @Valorum My apologies for my lack of knowledge about the military. If I had known that, maybe I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @Cadence And in-universe?

Comment: [Lower Decks](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/267.htm) is a pretty good overview of what the crew knows; what they're told, what they can see out of the windows and whatever scuttlebutt they share amongst themselves.

Comment: @Valorum Could you please turn your comments into an answer for me?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - Your merest whim is my most fervent command

Answer (score 1):

The episode [TNG: Lower Decks](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/267.htm) gives us a fair idea of what the ship's junior officers and civilians know. It seems to boil down to a mix of **publicly given orders**, **official announcements**, **reasoned speculation** and **straight-up gossip**.

---

### Orders:

Various crew members are given orders on the Main Bridge (helm, location, heading, etc), Main Engineering (transporter refinements, power, etc). Those orders seem to be pretty much public and are discussed freely by the crew.

> **PICARD:** Helm, change course for the Argaya system, maximum warp.
>
> **LAVELLE:** Aye, sir.
>
> **RIKER:** What happened to the rendezvous with the Clement?
>
> **PICARD:** I've just received new orders from Starfleet. We'll discuss it in the Observation lounge. Mister Data, Mister Worf.
> ...
> **SITO:** The Argaya system's close to the Cardassian border. I wonder why we're going there. How'd you like to be a spider under that table?
>
> **LAVELLE:** What?
>
> **SITO:** A spider under the table.
>
> **LAVELLE:** Is that like a fly on the wall?

### **Announcements.**

Periodically Picard and other senior officers will make announcements over the ship's intercom system to explain what's happening.

> PICARD [on Tannoy]: To all Starfleet personnel, this is the Captain. It is my sad duty to inform you that a member of the crew, Ensign Sito Jaxa has been lost in the line of duty. She was the finest example of a Starfleet officer, and a young woman of remarkable courage and strength of character. Her loss will be deeply felt by all who knew her. Picard out.

### Scuttlebutt

The crew speculate endlessly among themselves about secret orders. The irony is that one of their number knows full well what's happening, but keeps it to herself. Speculation is allowed, but breaking orders to disclose secret mission info isn't.

> **BEN:** It's your bet, Taurik. What I can't understand is why we're just sitting here so close to the Cardassian border.
>
> **LAVELLE:** It must have something to do with that escape pod we picked up. Don't you think, Sito?
>
> **SITO:** Maybe.
>
> **LAVELLE:** I wonder who was in it?
>
> **BEN:** You know what I heard? It was Ambassador Spock.
>
> **TAURIK:** That is most unlikely.
>
> **BEN:** That's what I was told.
>
> **TAURIK:** By whom?
>
> **BEN:** I can't say.

Comment: In short, "Most of the time, the crew *doesn't* know what's going on."

Comment: @T.J.L. - Probably most of the crewmen are too busy doing their jobs to worry about what's going on outside the ship. If your job is to keep the aft phaser bank degaussed, are you really that fussed that the ship is mapping a thing with its sensors or getting neck-deep in international politics?

Comment: Man, I _love_ degaussing the aft phaser banks and you're right, @Valorum I don't give a rat's patoot _what's_ going on outside the ship (or even in the forward phaser banks) when I'm up to my ears in aft phaser bank gauss.

Comment: @FreeMan - You do your job or people die. Leave the thinking and the politicking to the brass hats.